# How do you get a div to wrap around an image?

Tags: html, css

*Edit: I copied the wrong version of the code.*

This should be really easy, but nothing I've found on the internet has helped. At the moment my image looks like this:

[image]

But the white box (a `<div>` element with a white background) isn't wrapping around the picture, it's just staying at the bottom like that, despite being the parent tag of the `<img>`

Here's the html:

```
<div class="image-div">
    <a href="planner.html"> 
        <img class="screenshot" src="http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/images/4/47/Placeholder.png" alt="University Planner"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.screenshot {

    width:20%;
    height: 20%;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.image-div
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: It's funny that you call your `span` a `div`.

Comment: After your edit, you just need to change the display to `display: block;` or remove the whole display property.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a div, it's a span. Change the tag to be:

```
<div class="image-div">
    <a href="planner.html"> 
        <img class="screenshot" src="http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/images/4/47/Placeholder.png" alt="Planner"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Or, if you have to keep it a span, add `display:block;` property to it:

```
.image-div
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display:block;

}
```

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong code. I have the same problem with a `<div>` because it needs to be inline (otherwise the `<div>` takes up the whole page width)

Comment: @Miguel you can add a `width` property to control the width while removing the `inline` display. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: I could but ideally this same class will apply to many images so using a fixed width would be restrictive

Comment: You can't have that while giving the image a % width. You can use `display: inline-block;` but you need to give the child img a fixed width. I put a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/5nwRJ/

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep it the way it is, giving the `image-div` a `display: block;` but putting it in a container div with a fixed width. There are many solutions but I need more information from you.

Comment: I don't know why it worked, but setting the display to inline-block and giving it a fixed width was exactly what I wanted. How does that work?

Comment: That's what inline-block is for. You can consider a div with `inline-block` as `inline` for adjacent elements, and `block` for child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `div` dimensions and give image a `max-width` for scalability.  Also make it a `block` not `inline`.

### CSS:

```
.screenshot {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
.image-div {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    width:20%;
    height: 20%;
}
```

## [Teach you how to Douglas.](http://jsfiddle.net/uz3WV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
just add one more attribute float:left, with some width (if you want)
or
if { display:inline } no need then remove it from here, I've update your updated code below:
```

now copy paste below css:

```
.screenshot {

width:20%;
height: 20%;
border: solid black 1px;
}

.image-div
{
background-color: white;
padding: 10px;
display: inline; /* if no need then remove it */
overflow: hidden;
float: left; /* please add */
width: 88px; /* if you want to add some width */
}
```